# How to properly export the variable inside chrome api function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension that can store selected text from web page to my variable in javascript. I am using eventPage.js with the manifest code:

```js
"background": {
              "service_worker": "eventPage.js",  
              "type": "module"
       }
```

I can run my code in the background without clicking my extension first. I have created a context menu for my extension so I can click it whenever I want. And I can store the selected text in a web page. My code looks like this:

```js
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((onClickedData) => {
       const text = onClickedData.selectionText
})
```

onClickedData.selectionText is the selected text I got from the web page. I am storing that value in a variable "text". And This code is in eventPage.js. Now I want to export it to my main.js where I can modify the DOM. This is the code in eventPage.js to be exported to main.js:

```js
export const string = chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((onClickedData) => {
       const text = onClickedData.selectionText
       return text
})
```

This is my code in main.js:

```js
import {string} from "./eventPage.js"


clickMe.addEventListener('click', () => {
       console.log(string)
       // returns undefined
})
```

I didn't have an error with this code. It works completely fine. But the problem is that it logs out "undefined" even I declared a return in chrome.contextMenus. Why is that and How to get the selected text I got from web page in chome.contextMenus?

Comment: This code is doing nothing because that's not how events and listeners work, however luckily you don't need to pass any data: just use getSelection().toString() in your content script.

Comment: Can you write the code here? It would help me so greatly that I could cry. Thanks